Emulate Substance Painter edge wear in Blender material?
I'm trying to emulate the following edge wear map (generated in Substance Painter) in Blender:

One of the key aspects of this map that I am trying to recreate is the relatively low amount of high frequency detail. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in Blender. Here's what I've got:

I got this result by getting the dot product of the geometry's normal and a bevel node:

While it's okay, it has way more high frequency detail than I'd like. I think that Substance averages out the curvature over a given radius but I don't know how to do that in blender.
If anyone has tips to get my result closer to the substance result, I'd appreciate it greatly

I don't know whether this will help, but PixxO 3D posted a YT tutorial about creating an Edge Wear shader for Blender yesterday which uses two Bevel nodes. Use This Method To Improve Your Shaders -Edge Wear.
